# Expression for ( or approximation of ) series of odd terms in series representation of Bessel function of first kind?

Tags: sequences-and-series, approximation, bessel-functions

We know:

$$J_v(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{\Gamma(k+v+1)k!}\bigr(\frac{z}{2}\bigl)^{2k+v}  \      \ (Eq. 1)$$
$$s.t.\ (v,k)\in \mathbb N,z\in \mathbb R$$

courtesy of [Introduction to Bessel Functions](http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselI/introductions/Bessels/ShowAll.html) and that there are quite a few ways of approximating Bessel functions of the first kind (written above) asymptotically. 
 To move on, if we take $v=1$, then:
$$J_1(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{\Gamma(k+2)k!}\bigr(\frac{z}{2}\bigl)^{2k+1} \ \ \ \ (Eq.\ 2) $$
But I am interested in approximations for a series composed of the *odd* terms of the series representation above, $(Eq. 2)$. Namely $k \in \mathbb N_{odd}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [generalized hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function), with

\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{2k+1}}{\Gamma(2k+v+2)(2k+1)!}\left(\frac z2\right)^{4k+v+2}&=-\left(\frac z2\right)^{v+2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{\Gamma(2k+v+2)(2k+1)!}\left(\frac z2\right)^{4k}\\&=-\left(\frac z2\right)^{v+2}{}_0F_2\left(;-\frac32,\frac{v+3}2;\frac{z^4}{64}\right)\end{align}

One can also view this as a difference of the alternating and non-alternating series given by

$$J_v(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{\Gamma(k+v+1)k!}\left(\frac z2\right)^{2k+v}$$

$$I_v(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{\Gamma(k+v+1)k!}\left(\frac z2\right)^{2k+v}$$

> $$\frac{J_v(z)-I_v(z)}2=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{2k+1}}{\Gamma(2k+v+2)(2k+1)!}\left(\frac z2\right)^{4k+v+2}$$

where $I$ is the [modified Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions).

Comment: For the correct answer vote, you mind adding the expression for $E_{2,3}(z)$ ? Would make this that much more clear!

Comment: @user3108815 updated

Comment: @Simiply Beautiful Art ok so using the last line I should be able to solve the case I've written above quite easily? Please let me know if there are any mistakes with what should be the now obvious derivation.  I'll tack it on to your answer for specificity.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You asked for an expression for $E_{2,3}$ in your first comment, which I have provided.

Comment: I've edited your answer, I think someone will peer review then if there are no mistakes in my edit I'll mark it correct. I just went all the way with the derivations involved in the answer so as to be a complete reference for others with my question later. Thank you kindly, this was helpful indeed!

Comment: This doesn't seem right, now on second thought: what happened to the second factorial in the denominator? The Bessel function of the first kind's series representation includes a factorial function (in addition to the gamma function) in the denominator.

Comment: Oops haha, I missed that bit :p I'll update it in the morning. With certainty though, this is a hypergeometric function, and you can likely form a differential equation that describes your function of interest.

Comment: hahaha, hate to be that guy again, but did you miss the substitution of the $k!$ for $(2k+1)!$ in the denominator?

Comment: Hopefully fixed >.<